# How do I capture which button is clicked to change images in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to figure out which button is clicked in my function. The 'next' button is working fine but I do not want to make a different function for the 'previous' button just to decrease the imageIndex so the images can reverse.

Beginner here. Constructive comments welcomed.

```
JS:
    <script>
       var imageArray = ["IMG1","IMG2",
                     "IMG3","IMG4"];

      var imageIndex = 1;

     function changeImage()
     {  
        document.getElementById("currentImg").src = imageArray[imageIndex];
        imageIndex++;   
        if(imageIndex >= imageArray.length)
        {
            imageIndex = 0;
        }
    };          
</script>

HTML:
     <img src="img1" id="currentImg" alt="img">
     <button id="nextBtn" type="button" onclick="changeImage();">Next</button>
     <button id="prevBtn" type="button" onclick="changeImage();">Previous</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass `this` in the event handler of your buttons:

```
onclick="changeImage(this);"
```

Then `this` will be a reference to the button being clicked. In your function add a parameter:

```
function changeImage(btn) {
```

Which would then allow you to determine which button was clicked by its ID:

```
btn.id
```

Which would then either be `nextBtn` or `prevBtn` which you could use to check in an if statement for example.

Answer (score 0):

Let's get this working!

JS:

```
   var imageArray = ["IMG1","IMG2",
                 "IMG3","IMG4"];

  var imageIndex = 1;

 function changeImage(val)
 {  
    document.getElementById("currentImg").src = imageArray[imageIndex];
    imageIndex + val;   
    if(imageIndex >= imageArray.length || imageIndex < 0)
    {
        imageIndex = 0;
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
     <img src="img1" id="currentImg" alt="img">
     <button id="nextBtn" type="button" onclick="changeImage(1);">Next</button>
     <button id="prevBtn" type="button" onclick="changeImage(-1);">Previous</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always do this (not the prettiest, but still effective)

```
<script>
   //image array setup here
 function changeImage(direction)
 {  
    if (direction == "left") {
       // handle left action
    } else {
       // handle right action
    }
};
function goLeft(){
changeImage("left");
};
function goRight(){
changeImage("right");
};          
</script>
```

and then your buttons could be:

```
 <button id="nextBtn" type="button" onclick="goLeft();">Next</button>
 <button id="prevBtn" type="button" onclick="goRight();">Previous</button>
```

Have fun!